# Example of a function of two variables that has partial derivatives but the mixed derivative does not exist

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm working on an exercise on harmonic functions and stumbling upon finding a function of two variables that has partial derivatives with respect to each variable but the mixed derivative does not exist.

To be specific, I want to find a real-valued function of two real variables $x$ and $y$, $f(x, y)$ that satisfies both partial derivatives $f_{x}$ and $f_{y}$ each exist on an open interval $\mathit{I}$ but at least $f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}$ does not exist on that interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $$g(t)=
\begin{cases}
t^2, t\geq 0\\
-t^2, t<0
\end{cases}$$
It is easy to see that $g'$ exists everywhere but $g''$ exists everywhere except $0$.
Now take for example $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$.

Comment: Did you miss $g(0)=0$?

Comment: Why is that relevant?

Comment: You mentioned that $g'$ exists everywhere, how is that possible without $g(0)$'s existence?

Comment: Oh, you are right. It was a typo.